# Radical of an ideal - prove every prime ideal that contains $I$ also contains $\sqrt{I}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit and $I$ an ideal.
Please prove that every prime ideal that contains $I$ also contains $\sqrt{I}$.

I easily conclud that $I \subseteq \sqrt I$ but I couldn't find how to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathfrak a\subseteq \mathfrak p$. If $x^n\in\mathfrak a$ for some $n$; then $x^n\in\mathfrak p$, and since $\mathfrak p$ is prime...

Comment: Can you please explain more?  Notice that the prime ideal $P$ contains the ideal $I$, which means that $x^n \in I \subseteq P$ and we need to prove that $x \in P$

Comment: @RanKashtan Use the definition of "prime ideal".

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that. We don't know if $R$ is a final ring or not. Therefore, I can't tell the the prime ideal is the maximal ideal.

Comment: @RanKashtan What is the definition of "prime ideal"?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are two elements of $R$ such that their product ab is an element of $P$, then $a$ is in $P$ or $b$ is in $P$.

Comment: @RanKashtan Good. Now use that to deduce that $x^n\in\mathfrak p\implies x\in\mathfrak p$.